# Python odbc cursor: keeping persistent state after executing a query

Tags: python, cursor, odbc, hive

Lets say we have table_1 living in database_1.

```
import pyodbc
connection =  pyodbc.connect(dsn='hive', autocommit=True)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("USE database_1")
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table_1")
```

This will give a table not found error, because we have reset the database we were using back to the default when the cursor executes the next query. Is there a way to keep consistent state/bundle multiple queries into an execute statement in order to avoid this? I'm particularly interested in being able to set the number of mappers/reducers and be able to keep this state when I execute my next query. I know an alternative is just using Python to make the shell connect to Hive and execute an hql file but I'd rather not do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned that you can set things like the number of reducers in the ODBC connection string, e.g.

```
string = 'dsn=hive/driver/path;mapred.reduce.tasks=100;....'
connection = pyodbc.connect(string, autocommit=True)
```

This lets you use the specific setting you want in the connection; this doesn't solve the issue of switching database but it solves the other situations where you introduce settings into Hive, which was the bulk of my question.

Answer (score 1):

I suggests that you try few things:

1. I think that in most cases, if not all of them, you can specify the database that you want to work with using the connection string.
2. I see in [the documentation](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#execute) that the 'execute' command returns the cursor itself, even though I would try:

> cursor.execute("USE database_1").execute("SELECT * FROM table_1")

(Just in case that the docmentation is wrong)

3. This may actually work:

> cursor.execute("USE database_1")
>
> cursor.commit()
>
> cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table_1")

Plese update if any if this worked.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the first statement, but the second two options did not work.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell of `pyodbc` documentation there doesn't appear to be specific support for Hive.  If you are willing to entertain a different library, [pyhs2](https://github.com/BradRuderman/pyhs2) specifically supports connections with HiveServer2 (Hive 0.11 or newer, I think).  It can be installed with pip (`pip install pyhs2`), but at least on my Mint Linux 17 box I also had to install `libpython-dev` and `libsasl2-dev` first.

I mocked up a trivial approximation of your scenario in Hive (`table_1` inside `database_1` but not `default`):

```
hive> use default;
OK
Time taken: 0.324 seconds
hive> select * from table_1;
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10001]: Line 1:14 Table not found 'table_1'
hive> use database_1;
OK
Time taken: 0.333 seconds
hive> describe table_1;
OK
content                     string                              
Time taken: 0.777 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select * from table_1;
OK
this
is
some
sample
data
Time taken: 0.23 seconds, Fetched: 5 row(s)
```

So then this is a rudimentary script leveraging `pyhs2` to connect to Hive:

```
# Python 2.7
import pyhs2
from pyhs2.error import Pyhs2Exception

hql = "SELECT * FROM table_1"
with pyhs2.connect(
  host='localhost', port=10000, authMechanism="PLAIN", user="root",
  database="default"  # Of course it's possible just to specify database_1 here
) as db:
  with db.cursor() as cursor:

    try:
      print "Trying default database"
      cursor.execute(hql)
      for row in cursor.fetch(): print row
    except Pyhs2Exception as error:
      print(str(error))

    print "Switching databases to database_1"
    cursor.execute("use database_1")
    cursor.execute(hql)
    for row in cursor.fetch(): print row
```

This is the resulting output:

```
Trying default database
"Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10001]: Line 1:14 Table not found 'table_1'"
Switching databases to database_1
['this']
['is']
['some']
['sample']
['data']
```

As I noted in a comment line of the code, it is entirely possible to have just initiated the connection directly with `database_1` instead of `default`, but I wanted to try to emulate what you were doing with the code you posted in the question (and demonstrate the capability to switch databases after the connection has been initiated).

Anyway, hopefully food for thought if you're willing to entertain a non-`pyodbc` solution.